# rails way - how to add enrollment to course - course controller or roll controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I have a course model and a roll model (which points to the course and to the student).

```
course has many rolls
roll belongs to course
roll belongs to student
```

When viewing a visitor record (attended a class but not on the roll [attendance and event models not pertinent]) I want to be able to click a button to enroll them in the course and then take them to the edit view of the enrollment record (for specifying type of enrollment and any notes).

Adding a student to a course... controllers... should I have a method on the course to add the roll record or should I have a method on the roll?  After the record is created the controller should redirect to the rolls#edit.

I'm somewhat of a rails newbie and want to make sure I'm doing this the right way/rails way.  And I'm sure this type of question has been asked before, but my searches avail me naught-- I'm sure I'm not searching the right phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would link that button to RollsController#create. The other option you might be considering is CoursesController#update, but you're not really changing anything about the course itself, like its name, number of credits, or anything intrinsic to the course.

You're creating a new instance of an enrollment: a student in a course. RollsController#create.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but I want to preserve the ability for a "new" button on the rolls to create a new roll.  So will the create end up rendering the edit view?

Comment: Sounds like you want to handle 2 situations: 1) viewing visitor page, click to enroll, redirect to edit details of the enrollment; 2) viewing course enrollment page, click 'new' to fill in details of the enrollment. Is that right?

Comment: yes.  With the first option, the person is already assigned to the roll instance.  With the second option, the user will need to select a person to enroll.

Comment: And in case 2, the user will select a person to enroll and take care of the other details all at once, so no need to redirect to edit after creation, yes? No problem. Have the form you fill out in case 2, and the button from the original question, both go to rolls#create, and redirect to the edit form only if those details haven't been filled in yet. Otherwise, redirect to wherever you want situation 2 to go.